# In the modern benoni, what should I do if this happens?

Tags: opening, minor-variations, modern-benoni

Let's say the position looks like this:

```
[Title "Black to move"]
[FEN ""]

 1.d4 Nf6 2. c4 c5 dxc5
```

I usually do this:

```
[Title "Black to move"]
[FEN ""]

1.d4 Nf6 2. c4 c5 3. dxc5 e6 4. b4 a5
```

I have played this position only once, and won, but still this might repeat in a open tournament I might go soon, so I need help to figure this out, because in the videos I have seen for the Benoni, I can't really find this variation anywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In the modern benoni, what should I do if this happens

Your continuation is the strongest in my opinion. I would advise you not to change anything.

> because in the videos I have seen for the Benoni, I can't really find this variation anywhere.

Of course, because it is weak. The best White can do after your move, **in my opinion** is this:

```
[Title "BenOni"]
[fen ""]

1.d4 Nf6 2.c4 c5 3.dxc5 e6 4.b4 a5! 5.b5 Bxc5
```

Here, I would aim for `Bb2 + e3 + Nf3 + Be2` setup as White. Not ideal, but surely playable and the nearest towards equality I can get after that horrible `b4`...

If White tries to be "smart" about keeping the extra pawn, here is how I would play as Black:

```
[Title "BenOni"]
[fen ""]

1.d4 Nf6 2.c4 c5 3.dxc5 e6 4.b4 a5! $40 5.Bd2 ( 5.Qb3 axb4! 6.Qxb4 Na6! ) ( 5.Qa4 Na6! 6.a3? ( 6.Bd2? axb4 7.Bxb4 Nxb4! 8.Qxa8 Nc2+ 9.Kd2 Nxa1 $17 ) 6...axb4! $17 7.axb4?? Nc7! $19 ) 5...axb4! 6.Bxb4 Na6! $32 $40 7.Ba3 Nxc5 8.Bb2!? ( 8.Nf3? Rxa3! 9.Nxa3 Qa5+ 10.Qd2 Qxa3 $17)
```

Your only problem after `b5` will be that you must play `...d5` which turns the game into positional battle. There will be no wild tactical positions anymore ( but still you will stand better ) so you will have to adapt **psychologically** to this fact ( tactical players hate "dry" positions and positional ones hate "wild" positions ). Try not to fall for this psychological trick. That is my last advice and a warning.

Good luck on the tournament!

Comment: I really like your points. If I don't get a better answer, which is unlikely, I will pick this.

Comment: Also I don't have any problems playing a positional battle, I'd complicate it more that Tal himself and strike. :p

Comment: @MikhailTal: Then you will probably win such positions. I have updated my answer to cover all lines in which White tries stubbornly to keep the extra pawn. As for accepting the answer, no problem just take your time :)

Comment: By the way, wouldn't d5 turn this game into an IQP position? Lots of attacking chances there, because not so many pieces are exchanged. But there is the tactical weapon Bxf6 be sort of a problem after cxd5 exd5? It is either king safety or a pawn.

Comment: @MikhailTal: It depends, you could take with a knight or queen. You don't need to play it fast since you have lead in development. I would castle first, and only then push it. BTW, I have edited the second diagram with a stronger response to `Qa4`, please take a look. And yes, **you** could turn it into IQP if you wish, it is up to you. I think that such position is good for Black because of his lead in development...

Comment: Yeah, good point. Although I favour IQP positions because of me being an avid Alapin player, I think that an knight take here would be better. Thank you.

Comment: One more thing. Most engines I have suggest a7a5, while Deep Fritz thinks b7b6 is better. I cannot understand why, other than the idea of the pressure with Bxb4.

Comment: @MikhailTal: It is a matter of taste I think. Even if Fritz does prefer `b6`, I bet the evaluation is **slightly** different that `a5`, for example `b6` having `-0.80` and `a5` having `-0.75` or something similar. I prefer `a5` because it opens more lines and **fractures** White pawn structure. With `b6` White can ignore the threat with something like `Bb2` and after `...bxc5` play `b5!` staying in the game since his pawn structure remains healthy.

Answer (score 1):

The line you play is fine.

After 5.b5, Bxc5 the position favors black.

bxa5 leaves white with a crap pawn structure.

5. a3 just loses a pawn for white

White has nothing after 4...a5